# how to authenticate username and password by calling wcf web service in android? & how to pass username and password along with request?

Tags: android, web-services

I am new to android please help me.
 This is code i have tried for:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);

btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pwd);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);>
```

How to pass request parameters?

```
  PropertyInfo p1=new PropertyInfo()
  p1.setName("username");
  p1.setValue("nitinr");
  request.addProperty(p1);
  PropertyInfo p2=new PropertyInfo();
  p2.setName("password");
  p2.setValue("123");
  request.addProperty(p2);
```

How to do coding for this?
I dont know about how to parse the output of the response?
and also guide about what will be the response?

```
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

  envelope.dotNet = true;                
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);                             
  HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  //invkoe web service and get result 
  try {                      
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
tv.setText(response.toString());
  } catch (Exception exception) {                            
tv.setText(exception.toString());                                       
  }   

if(username.equals("nitinr")){
if(password.equals("123")){
       onClick(v);
} else{
lblResult.findViewById(R.id.tv_link);
}
}else{
   btnLogin.findViewById(R.id.tv_valid)
}
    }

    });

 }
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Welcome.class);
startActivity(i);

  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using soap webservice then you need to check your service for response of the aservice action you are calling.

e.g. it might return 1 for successful login or -1 for invalid user or password, 0 for user doesnot exist.

```
/**
 * Login web services to authenticate the user.
 * @param Uname
 * @param Pword
 * @return
 */
public static int loginCheck(String Uname, String Pword){
    int id= 0;

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,SOAPLOGINMETHOD);

    request.addProperty("username",Uname);
    request.addProperty("password",Pword);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);


    try{
        httpTransport.call(SOAPLOGINACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.d("parameter", response.getProperty(0).toString());
        id=Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
        }
        catch (Exception exception){

            Log.d("Login Web Service Exception",exception.toString());
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }


    return id;
}
```

the use the return as:

```
public void onLoginClick(View view){
    userName=userNameTxt.getText().toString();
    password=passwordTxt.getText().toString();
    int uId=WebMethod.loginCheck(userName, password);
    if(uId >0){
    // Do what you want with it
    }
```